# Issue displaying search results

Tags: swift, uitableview

Essentially I have tableview with JSON data and a search controller for the user to quickly find values from the response. While the tableview data loads initially when attempting to search I get the error `index out of range`. The error occurs inside the cellForRowAt function. The following is what I am currently doing:

```
var sections = [customerListSection]()
var structure = [customerList]()

var searchsections = [customerListSection]()
var searchstruct = [customerList]()



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let section = sections[section]
    let searchsection = searchsections[section]
    
    if isFiltering() {
        return searchsection.count
    }
    return section.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]

    let customerList: customerList
    if isFiltering() {
        customerList = searchstruct[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        customerList = item
    }
  return cell
}


struct customerListSection {
    let customerType : String
    var items : [customerList]
}

struct customerList: Decodable {
    let customerid: Int
    let customer: String
    let type: String
}
```

Comment: Well you've got an obvious mismatch. The number of rows comes from searchsections[section] but then you get the data by indexing into searchstruct instead. Perhaps you are confused about how your data model works?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems that there are multiple sections, so you need to implement `numberOfSections(in:)`method.

> If you do not implement this method, the table configures the table with one section.)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614860-numberofsections

And since the number of rows is the number of items, not the number of sections, the `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` method should return `items.count`.

The following is the modified code:

```swift
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if isFiltering() {
        return searchsections.count
    }
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isFiltering() {
        return searchsections[section].items.count
    }
        return sections[section].items.count
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let customerList: customerList
    if isFiltering() {
        customerList = searchsections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        customerList = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    cell.textLabel!.text = customerList.customer

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It no longer crashes with that error, but once searching nothing appears on the screen. Blank results always - any suggestions?

Comment: @MarkLyson Since you have posted a new question I assume this answer has resolved this question?

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, do you know why the results are not displaying when searching? I will mark this as the answer, its just not displaying anything

Comment: @MarkLyson
I can't judge exactly from the posted code, but I guess the reason may be that only the value is assigned to `let customerList: customerList`, but it is not used.

For example, I think you need to configure the UI element of the cell like `cell.textLabel?.text = customerList.customer` before returning the cell.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this to the post, of course I am doing that as well - initially records are shown, but on filter nothing is ever displayed

Comment: Would you suggest I try anything else? I think it has something to do with either how  `searchsections` is being populated

Comment: can you show the code where you filter the data i think there is some problem.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly, because I don't know how the filtering logic is from the code you posted, but you could check what the value of `searchsections` is if `isFiltering() == true`.